# un able to insert data into database using php

Tags: php, mysql

this php code is written at the end of of my file

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $Jobtitle = $_POST['jobtitle'];
  $Firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $Lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $Name=$Firstname+$Lastname;
  $Sin = $_POST['sin'];
  $Phone = $_POST['phone'];
  $Email = $_POST['email'];
  $Address = $_POST['address'];
  $Postal = $_POST['postal'];
  $State = $_POST['state'];
  $Country = $_POST['country'];
  $Skill = $_POST['skill'];
  $Owntransport = $_POST['owntransport'];
  $ADate = $_POST['a-date'];
  $Workpermit = $_POST['workpermit'];
  $Daysavailable = $_POST['days-available'];
  $Strength = $_POST['strength'];
  $eFirstname = $_POST['efirstname'];
  $eLastname = $_POST['elastname'];
  $eName=$eFirstname+$eLastname;
  $ePhone = $_POST['ephone'];
  $query=" INSERT INTO `general`(`jobtitle`, `name`, `sin`, `pno`, `email`, `address`, `doc`, `skills`, `transport`, `avadate`, `authorize`, `days`, `strength`, `ename`, `ephone`) VALUES ('{$Jobtitle}','{$Name}','{$Sin}','{$Phone}','{$Email}','{$Address}','{$Postal}','{$State}','{$Country}','{$Skill}','{$Owntransport}','{$ADate}','{$Workpermit}','{$Daysavailable}','{$Strength}','{$eName}','{$ePhone}')";
 // $query = "INSERT INTO info (name,password,gender,hobby,phone no,dob,message) VALUES ('{$Name}','{$Password}','{$Gender}','{$Hobby}','{$Phone}','{$Dob}','{$Message}')";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if($result)
  {
    echo "data entered";
  }
  unset($_POST);
}
else{
  echo "error in entering data";
}
```

?>

this is the button tag

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"name="submit"value="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

this is the form tag

```
<form method="post" id="contactform" action="#" role="form">
```

connection .php file giving me the connection to database but I am unable to store the data in databse it gives me the error that 
data is not entered

Comment: first of all you should not be using mysql_* functions. read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: What is the error you getting while inserting ?

Comment: @KailashYadav it just runs the else function and what I should use instead of mysql_* function?

Comment: Are you using apostrophes `'` in any of your fields? Since you didn't escape any of them, this can cause errors.

Comment: You have to change `input` `type` `button` to `submit` and try again. Looks like it's not submitting the form unless you using JS.

Comment: After echoing "error in entering data" add this: `mysql_error()`

Comment: You should make use of PDO or Mysqli, http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059 mysql is deprecated in php 5.5 and totally removed from php 7

Comment: `$Name=$Firstname+$Lastname;` that isn't how it works.

Comment: change `$Name=$Firstname+$Lastname;` to `$Name=$Firstname . ' ' .  $Lastname;`

Comment: Plus, all you've shown us is the form tag and no inputs. Time to learn how to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Issue it that, you are using `15 columns` and trying to update `17 values`.

I think you missed `state` and `postal` columns.

**Side Note:**

Two more issues:

1. Using `mysql_*` extension its deprecated and not available in PHP 7.
2. Your code is open for SQL Injection.

**Suggestion:**

Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` for point 1.

For debugging, always use PHP `error_reprting` active in your code.

Comment: amongst other things